# Android studio build.gradle for Android 4.0

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, build.gradle

my `mainfest.xml` already the target build API version,
I can debug my app through usb mode, 
when I start to `build -> buildAPK(s)` via android studio error will show,

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':CordovaLib' )
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START

    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:2.5.3+164'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.0' , { exclude module: 'support-v4' })
}
```

in my cordova module's build.gradle

```
android {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    publishNonDefault true

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

error when click build->buildAPK(s) via android studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\usessa\eclipse-android-workspace\Android_Studio_Project\Android%20Studio%20Project\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\usessa\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\support-annotations\27.0.2\b9ef4342c934a1a8b107506273dc8061662a322\support-annotations-27.0.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [support-annotations-27.0.2.jar:android/support/annotation/StringRes.class]))
```

and i go to the folder found i can't remove the 'componentClasses.jar' say the file is locked,

anything i missing?

after running `gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Android%20Studio%20Project'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
         https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
         https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 > com.android.tool
s.lint:lint:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.0.1 > com.android.to
ols.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
--scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

after run  `gradle -q dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath`

```
debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for v
+--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
+--- project :CordovaLib
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3
|    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.3
|    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5
|    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5
|         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2
|         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5) -> 4.31.0
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0
|    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|    |    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.31.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.31.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.31.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.31.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.31.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-places:4.31.0
|    |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.31.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:4.31.0
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0 (*)
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0 (*)
+--- com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:2.5.3+164
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0 -> 11.6.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.6.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite-license:11.6.
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:11.6.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass-license:11.6.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-license:11.6.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1 -> 1.0.2
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.
     |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-licens
     |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.6
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl-license
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl-lic
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-license:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.6
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.6
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0
     |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.0
     |    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 ->
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-license:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework-license:11.6
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license:11.6.
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (
     |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps-license:11.6
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-license:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.6.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11
     |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.6.0
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-crash-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fido:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fido-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common-license:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.6.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid-license:11.6.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api-license:11.6
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common-license:11.6.
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-license:11.6.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.6.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet-license:11.6.0
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.6.0
          +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0 (*)
          +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
          \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable-license:11.6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath
```

for list the all the dependencies that is included in dependencies and other modules that you have included,and identify the `support-annotations` is included by which support-annotations.
if both have a different version,simple solution is add `support-annotations-27.0.2` in gradle file

Answer (score 0):

i change the build.gradle as below and it works

myApp
CordovaModule

build.gradle for project,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // IMPORTANT
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    // IMPORTANT
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
    compileSdkVersion 99
    buildToolsVersion "99.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whatever.i.like"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 99
        versionName "99.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }   
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'build-data.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation (project(':CordovaModule') ,{ exclude module: 'support-v4' })    
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    implementation ('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2',{  exclude module: 'support-v4'})
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0',{  exclude module: 'support-v4'})
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation ('com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:2.5.3+164',{
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-plus'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
    })
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:12.0.0')
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0')
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

CorvodaModule's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 99
    buildToolsVersion "99.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 99
        versionName "99.0"
    }
    publishNonDefault true
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

after that, clean and rebuild
everything is fine,